# Send form when enter is clicked inside textarea jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
           var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
           $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
           $("#usermsg").val("");
           return false;
         });
       });
```

This is my html

```
<form name="message" action="" id="message">
 <textarea  name="usermsg" id="usermsg"></textarea>
 <div class="submit"><input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send"></div>
</form>
```

as this moment the form can be sent only by pressing the button. However, I want to make it so its sent also by clicking enter inside the textarea. But I also need to be able to break lines by pressing shift + enter.

How can I do this in jquery? I tried:

```
     $("#usermsg").keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
       var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
        $("#usermsg").val("");
        return false;
      }
    });
```

But i cant make it to break line on shift press.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `shiftKey` property of event object

```js
$("#usermsg").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {  
    console.log(e.shiftKey ? 'Shift & Enter' : 'Enter only')
    if (!e.shiftKey) {
      // do ajax here
      return false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="message" action="" id="message">
 <textarea  name="usermsg" id="usermsg"></textarea>
 <div class="submit"><input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: great, thank you. By the way, is there any way to merge both functions in one? So the form gets sent by both pressing the button and pressing enter?

Comment: Instead of using click event on button use submit event on form and then do `$('#message').submit()` in the keypress